# How to insert current date shortcode for hugo website

Tags: javascript, iframe, hugo, hugo-shortcode

So far I have successfully put an iframe shortcode on my site.

What I want to do is put today's date into the iframe url where I have the date, like this where I have an old static date:

```
{{< charts "https://unnamed.website/dontguess/performance_chart_viewer.aspx?environment=DEV&date=2022-03-31&type=Daily_CPU" >}}
```

Here is my "charts" shortcode definition for the iframe:

```
<iframe src="{{.Get 0}}"&type=Daily_CPU width="1080" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is my "date" shortcode with some javascript to get today's date:

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.write(today);
</script>
```

I have been trying a hand full of things and nothing seems to work right, so far.

I thought this would have worked in the iframe shortcode definition, but it does not:

```
<iframe src="{{.Get 0}}{{< date >}}"&type=Daily_CPU width="1080" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here. Can you help me? Is there an easier way that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: could it be `src="{{.Get 0}}&date={{< date >}}&type=Daily_CPU"` ?

Comment: I've tried that too. That's not working like I would have expected either.

Comment: Does your front matter have a date?

Comment: No date in the front matter on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should lead you in the right direction...

{{< charts "https://unnamed.website/dontguess/performance_chart_viewer.aspx?environment=DEV&date=2022-03-31&type=Daily_CPU" >}}

Becomes:

{{< charts "https://unnamed.website/dontguess/performance_chart_viewer.aspx?environment=DEV&date={{now.Format | "YOUR NEEDED FORMAT HERE"}}&type=Daily_CPU" >}}